# Tensor product and tor functor for the structure sheaf of a complement

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface and $C$ a subcurve of $X$. Denote by $j:X\backslash C \to X$ the natural immersion. I have made the following computations but would like to verify it:

1) $j_*\mathcal{O}_{X\backslash C} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{O}_C=0$ because for any $x \in C$, closed point, $\mathcal{I}_{C|X}=(f_x)$ for some $f_x \in \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and $(j_*\mathcal{O}_{X\backslash C})_x=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}[1/f_x]$ which directly implies the conclusion.

2) For each $x \in X$, $\mathrm{Tor}^1_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}(\mathcal{O}_{C,x},(j_*\mathcal{O}_{X\backslash C})_x)=0$ using the above description and that of $\mathrm{Tor}^1_R(R/(r),-)$, for a ring $R$.

Are these correct? I wanted to be sure since as an application I am getting something that I had not expected, which I have not elaborated in this question.